# Linux custom executable globally available

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I downloaded the Google App Engine as a zip format, unzipped it to /usr/local/google_engine

Now I need to run a python script from that folder all the time. How do I make it available no matter where my path is? ie: when i'm in /usr/something/ i can execute the script by just calling script.py?

Can I do this without aliasing or without using bash scripts?

Comment: Set your `PATH`? Like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/google_engine`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Edit your .bashrc to add the desired directory on the PATH environmental variable.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/google_app_engine/bin:$PATH
```

then, either start new terminal or do,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now try to run the script from anywhere.

Another way you can do it without even touching the .bashrc would be to create a symlink by doing something like,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/google_app_engine/bin/script.py /usr/bin/script.py
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ln -s /usr/local/google_app_engine/bin/script.py /usr/bin/script.py`? The destination with `ln`, as with most commands, is the last parameter.

Comment: It's easy to remember if you think that it works just like `cp`.

Comment: Why can't I just copy the binary files to `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/google_app_engine/bin/script.py /usr/bin/script.py ` Rocks!

Comment: `zsh: too many levels of symbolic links: /usr/bin/script.py`

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this. As Kal mentioned above you can add the folder to the path variable by adding

```
export PATH=/usr/local/google_app_engine/bin:$PATH1
```

to your .bashrc. Alternatively, if the command is just one script you can move or copy it to `/usr/bin`. This will make it accessible as a command from anywhere.

If you want to create a command to do this without moving `script.py` then you can create a bash file that calls it with a fixed path then put that in `/usr/bin`