# PHP Propel on macOS Sierra unable to create working symlink

Tags: php, macos, symlink, propel, propel2

The manual of propel says:

In order to allow an easier execution of the script, you can also add the propel generator’s bin/ directory to your PATH, or create a symlink. For example:

```
$ cd myproject
$ ln -s vendor/bin/propel propel
```

If I do this, the symlink is created, but if I run propel I get the following error:

```
-bash: propel: command not found
```

Result of ln -al

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  group     17 11 jan 10:47 propel -> vendor/bin/propel
```

How can I solve this?

Note: calling vendor/bin/propel is working correctly

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it work and installed. it doesn't seem very premising at all, I have used the composer to install it, and I have got a lots of errors.

Comment: Yes I did. Installing with composer did not generate any errors.

Only thing is that I cannot use the 'propel' command, but need to use the ./propel command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
./propel

Calling only 'propel' should look for global executable

Comment: That works, why is only 'propel' for global executables? Isn't there a way to make just typing 'propel' work?

(without changing the global path)

Comment: No. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235125/linux-custom-executable-globally-available

Comment: I might be missing the ./name part in this link?